# Count the number of passing servlets

Tags: jsp, servlets

```
 /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    /**
     *
     * @author neil
     */
    public class No1 extends HttpServlet {

        /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP
     * <code>GET</code> and
     * <code>POST</code> methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */


     protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            try {
                /* This is how my No1 servlet looks like*/
            /*I used the textbox name as number in html form*/
            String let = request.getParameter("number");
            /*Convert thw string to integer and assign to num variable*/
            int num = Integer.parseInt(let);

            RequestDispatcher dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("No2");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);


        }finally {            
            out.close();
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP
     * <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP
     * <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>
}
```

I have created 4 servlets call No1, No2, No3, No4. Then when runs the file it display a JSP page with a text box to insert the servlet name like No1, No2…. Each servlet page is forward to next page using dispatcher. So No1 servlet is forwarded to No2, No2 is forwarded to No3 and No3 for No4. If I enter No1 in text box I want to display the answer as 4, if enter No2 should display the 3. It is the number of passing servlet, I try to use for loop, but it does not work, please can you help me.

Comment: you mean total number of hits on a particular page of your website?

Comment: I sent the request comes to 1st servlet to 5th servlet by passing request from 1 to 2, 2 to 3, 3 to 4, 4to 5. So if someone fill the html form as No1(that is servlet 1)and click ok it should provide the answer as 5 as the request send to last servlet. If someone enter No3 the answer should 2. That is what i want to do.